# How to change `ibus` keyboard layout in XFCE?

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce, ibus

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04, but I've installed `xubuntu-desktop` and I mostly use that desktop environment.

I needed a phonetic Tamil keyboard layout,  so for that I had to install something called `ibus`. Ibus works, but now that I've set it as the manager of keyboard layouts, I can no longer figure out how to switch between layouts when in XFCE.  The keyboard layout switcher in the panel worked before,  but it does nothing now that I've activated `ibus`.

The only way I've found to switch is to log out., log into Lubuntu desktop,  change the layout,  log out again,  and then log into XFCE again.  That's quite inconvenient,  though,  when I'm alternating between typing in different languages.

How can I switch in a more convenient way while staying in XFCE?

Comment: Guessing: Perhaps you can add the other keyboard layout(s) to IBus and use IBus for switching between them instead of the XFCE layout switcher.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, I've added both of them in ibus. But how do I switch ibus layouts in XFCE?

Comment: I just checked on my (pure) Xubuntu 16.04, and I can either use the input source indicator in the top panel or the shortcut <Super>+<Space>. Possibly there is an issue with using xubuntu-desktop on a Lubuntu install.

Comment: @Fiksdal, not sure if it is the same, but I have a problem using Cinnamon (2.6) and ibus in 16.04: when adding "xim keyboards" through ibus, then when using the ibus indicator to change layouts the xim ones "don't work".  I have to use the "non ibus" indicator to successfully use the xim keyboards.  This is clearly a regression as under 14.04 the ibus indicator could successfully switch and use xim keyboards.  So does this match what you see on Xubuntu as well?

Comment: @rik-shaw I'm not sure, it's a bit confusing. I've gotten it to work perfectly on  Lubuntu 16.04 and in Unity. I think it miight be a problem with XFCE, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I just did a clean install of Xubuntu 16.04, and it still doesn't work. I'm talking about `ibus-m17n`, the phonetic Tamil keyboard. I can switch to it, but no characters actually appear on the screen. But it worked yesterday in Lubuntu, and also in Unity. Looks like maybe there is some problem with XFCE. I will have to do another install of Lubuntu and maybe just forget about XFCE.

Comment: I asked for more info on http://askubuntu.com/q/780119

Comment: @rik-shaw: How did you install Cinnamon? The version available in the official Xenial archive is 2.8. (Probably it would be better if you asked a separate question about it.)